# How to split a string by tabs but only once per occurrence

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string structured like this:

```
"I\thave\ta\t\tstring"
```

And in order split by tabs I used this method:

```
text = [splits for splits in row.split("\t") if splits is not ""]
```

Now this method removes all tabs from the string but I want it to remove only the first occurrence of a tab after a word so it would end up like this:

```
"Ihavea\tstring"
```

Is there a way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `re.split` on a negative look behind assertion should do:

```
import re

s = ''.join(re.split(r'(?<!\t)\t', row))
print(s)
# 'Ihavea\tstring'
```

The assertion `(?<!\t)` prevents a split on a `\t` which was preceded by another `\t`.

You can use `re.sub` if you do not actually need the items from the split:

```
s = re.sub(r'(?<!\t)\t', '', row)
print(s)
# 'Ihavea\tstring'
```

Answer (score 2):

List comprehension is also a way to go if you want to avoid to import the re module:

```
row = "I\thave\ta\t\tstring"
text = [splits if splits else "\t"  for splits in row.split("\t")]
"".join(text)
#'Ihavea\tstring'
```

An empty string is in a boolean context false and empty list elements will be generated for every consecutive split-char ("\t" in this case)

Answer (score 1):

To keep it simple you can use [`re.split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split)

```
from re import split
text = "I\thave\ta\t\tstring"
split_string = split(r'\t+', text)  #Gives ['I', 'have', 'a', 'string']
```

The regular expression `r'\t+'` basically just groups all consecutive tabs together.

Comment: Keep in mind this is strictly for splitting a string up. You can easily join them back together with `"".join(split_string)`

Comment: I admit that @MosesKoledoye has a better answer because my answer will just remove all tabs will splitting on them, where his will preserve one if there are multiple.

Answer (score 0):

What about the string split method, using one occurrence only:

```
text = "I\thave\ta\t\tstring"
text.split("\t", 1)
```